# Pulling from CSV file that has a list, then loop

Tags: python, csv

I am pretty new to Python, only really messed with API. I am trying to get the following code to loop, and on each loop pull a new value for the "client" from a CSV file. On each line in the CSV file there is a client name, I want it to read the CSV, pull the name from line 1, loop, pull the name from line 2 and so on.. how would I go about doing this?

````
import json, getpass, csv, requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
username = input("Enter GTAX username: ")
password = getpass.getpass('Enter GTAX Password: ')
client = 'Name from line 1 - after loop line 2 and so on'
query = {'name': client}
response_API = requests.get(
        'https://example.com/api/v1/clients',
        auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password), timeout=10, params=query)

data = response_API.text
parse_json = json.loads(data)
id = parse_json['data'][0]['id']

properties = {
  "qualifier": {
    "value": "qualify",
    "required": True,
    "active": True
  },
  "presi": {
    "value": True,
    "required": True,
    "active": True
  },
  "pool": {
    "value": "VM",
    "required": False,
    "active": True
  }
}
putproperties = requests.put(
  f'https://example.com/api/v1/clients/{id}/properties/user',
  auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password), timeout=10, verify=False, data=json.dumps(properties))
status1 = putproperties.status_code
print(status1)```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally reading a csv is pretty straight forward. Here is my clients.csv:

```
client_name,client_id
John Doe,1
Max Mustermann,2
```

I then simply read it with csv library, line by line as a dictionary:

```py
import csv


def do_something_with_client(name):
    print(name)


with open('clients.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for line in reader:
        do_something_with_client(line["client_name"])
```

If your CSV does not have a header, you can provide one:

```py
reader = csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=["client_name", "client_id"])
```

You can refer to the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#examples) to find more examples on how to use the csv library.